# Windows Bluetooth LE connection speed

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-rt

We got a development chip for Bluetooth 5.0 that we want to integrate in our peripherals.
For our first testing purposes we used the same chip two times which emulated a COM port. There we
were able to connect the two devices and have a connection speed of 2MBit (proofed to have that by
checking the values in the debugger).

So.. Now we wanted to switch to a native API via WinRT and GATT services. The laptop I use here supports
bluetooth 5.1 (Dell XPS13 with an Killer AX 1650 Dual Chip for WLAN and Bluetooth 5.1) so I assume that
this should do the trick.

Anyway I used the WinRT Bluetooth LE sample from https://github.com/oldnewthing/Windows-universal-samples to setup a connection and receive data but according to the device we could not manage to
to setup the connection to have 2MBit but rather only 1MBit which is a bit too less for our use case.

Is there anything I can do with the WinRT API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client) such that I can at least check which connection speed is selected or even better
can I choose a speed somewhere?

The closest thing I found was the PDU size (read only) only in the GATT Session object but no notice on the speed.

Or is there any other API I could use here beside the WinRT?

Comment: Have you read this article about requirements to maximise BLE throughput speed? https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-speed-maximum-throughput/

Comment: The thing is that if 2 peripheral devices communicate with each other the phys layer indicates a 2MBit connection whereas with my laptop it only shows a 1MBit (BT standard...) rate.

Comment: You max speed is the minimum speed in the chain.  Are any of your Ethernet (including WLAN) device only able to support 1MB rate?  There is an upload rate and download rate on a WLAN that is different.

Comment: @jdweng: thanks for the input - if it's true what you say then seems that the Intel chip (aka the Killer system) is the bottleneck. I couldn't find any reference though why that should be thecase.... Anyway it's actually hard to understand why a high GHz PC system does not support fast BLE (2MBit) 5.0 and a peripheral - low power - chip actually does....

Comment: Maybe there is a contradiction between BLE (Low Energy) and High Speed.  The device has to be HDR (High Data Rate) for 2MB. Older devices a 10mw and HDR 100mw

Comment: The problem is definitely not on the peripheral side but rather on the windows chip. With two identical dongles we actually can proof that the 2MB is working but not if it's connected with my laptop and the intel chip...